# Use "default channel grouping" as a dimension in Google Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, grouping, google-analytics-api, channel

I would like to use the Google Analytics API to get the data displayed on the Acquisition Overview webpage. Especially, I need to get the sessions (formerly called visits) break by Default channel grouping : Direct, Organic Search, Referral, Social, Paid Search, Email, Display and (Other).

As explained [here](http://www.seerinteractive.com/blog/new-google-analytics-channel-groupings#definitionofchannels), these groups are based on regex. Therefore, it might be possible to recode these rules, but I would prefer to use these groups as a dimension.

I googled it and most of the answers are referring to Multi-Channel Funnels (MCF), but according to the [MCF dimensions & metrics reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/dimsmets/), it's more about conversion.

Does anyone know how to use the Google Analytics API (or GA MCF API) to get such data ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acutaly I think you should be looking at the [Core Reporting Api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference) and [dimensions and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets)

The thing that's going to be a little tricky is that first column.  That column is Traffic Type and not something you can export directly.  It is calculated based upon Source / medium.

Direct = Source not equal (direct) and Medium not equal to organic referral and cpc

Campaign = Source not equal to (direct) and Medium not equal to organic referral and cpc

organic = Medium is equal to organic

paid = medium is equal to cpc

I cant remember what social was I will have to look into that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !

Unfortunately, I have to reproduce the same results than on the web client.

Unless I'm mistaken, these default groups are based on "Source", "Medium", "Ad Distribution Network" and "Social Source referral" (http://tinyurl.com/gagroups).

I would prefer to use these groups as a dimension instead of recoding the rules (to reduce the number of requests and to be more flexible if the rules change on Google side).

Comment: I just request ga:sourceMedium dimension and split it out. This way I created my own TrafficSource Dimension doing this.   http://www.daimto.com/google-analytics-traffic-type/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try our method!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link where you can find the GA definitions for Default Channel Groupings:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3297892?hl=en&ref_topic=3125765

When you go to this link, just click on the edit icon for the channel whose definition you want to see.

For example, for Social, the definition is:

Social Source Referral exactly matches Yes
OR
Medium matches regex ^(social|social-network|social-media|sm|social network|social media)$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was wondering if I can use these Default Channel Grouping as dimensions (with something like "ga:channelGrouping" as dimension), without recoding the rules described in the page that you mention.

Comment: There has been a suggestion to Google to support this as you are describing but to date I believe this is the only option. Would appreciate an upvote if the link above helped you :-) thanks! https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!starred/analytics/BMLDm6J4HO4

Comment: I've finaly found a solution thanks to @maggieto : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=channel_grouping (i've miss this feature during my searchs, or it was not available then)